# how to setup separate DNS endpoints for all different Apps running in Kubernetes Cluster??? (AWS/GCP/AZURE)

Tags: kubernetes, dns

**Can DNS point to specific port?**

---

### **how to setup separate DNS endpoints for all different Apps running in Kubernetes Cluster???**(AWS/GCP/AZURE)

### For example:

app1  service running on Nodeport: 30001

app2  service  running on Nodeport: 30002

---

app1 endpoint DNS should be **www.app1.com**

app2 endpoint DNS should be **www.app2.com**

Answer (score 2):

You need use LoadBalancer type service instead of NodePort type.But creating a new load balancer for each and every app is costly so alternatively you can use [kubernetes ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). There are different ingress controllers such as [nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) which implements the ingress API.